# Submitting a search in website with Jsoup

Tags: android, html, search, jsoup

I want to create an app that allows me to search for a city in this weather site.
I would like you to return the site corresponding to the search performed.
I tried to do this with an EditText and a Button, but the search does not seem to work, because the page returned is the same as the initial one.

How can I solve this problem?

This is my code:

```html
final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit);
        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.testo);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.clicca);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Connection.Response res = null;
            Document doc;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ilmeteo.it/meteo/cerca")
                            .data("citta", "bari")
                            .post();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                textView.setText(doc.location());
            }
        });
```

This is the site's HTML code:

```html
<div id="search">
<a id="search-logo" href="https://www.ilmeteo.it" title="IL Meteo - Home Page"></a>
<a id="search-arrow" href="javascript:;" onclick="toggleSearchMenu('main');"></a>
<form id="form-search0" name="search0" action="https://www.ilmeteo.it/meteo/cerca" method="get" onsubmit="return CheckSearchForm0()">
<input id="search-main" name="citta" value="" size="17" maxlength="64" class="txtSearch" onfocus="this.className='txtSearch';openSearchMenu('main');virginSearch=false;" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.className='txtSearch txtSearchE'" title="Cerca comune o località" autocomplete="Off" tabindex="1" onkeyup="ajax_showOptions(this,'type=IT&amp;sort=smart',event)" type="text">
</form>
<a id="search-button" href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#form-search0').submit()"></a>

<div id="fav-search-cont"><span id="fav-search"></span></div>

</div>
```

**EDIT**

Thank you all! Your answers have solved my problem :)
But I have problems with another weather site. How do I instead from this other site do the same operation as before?

P.S .: the problem of this site is the mandatory click of the city to search and that next to the city in the URL there is a code, like this "http://www.meteo.it/meteo/roma-58091".

This is the second site's HTML code:

```html
<div class="pksrc">
   <form class="search-form" onsubmit="return false">
    <fieldset class="icon-lens">
     <input type="hidden" id="searchid" disabled="" value="">
     <input type="hidden" id="searchtarget" value="_blank">
     <input type="text" class="query " id="searchinput" name="search" value="" placeholder="Cerca località" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </fieldset>
   </form>
   <div id="search-menu"></div>
   <ul id="search-option">
    <li><a href="/meteo/milano-15146" title="Milano">Milano</a></li>
    <li><a href="/meteo/roma-58091" title="Roma">Roma</a></li>
    <li><a href="/meteo/napoli-63049" title="Napoli">Napoli</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: D, you can also get the page by passing the city as a parameter in the search. Ex: `https://www.ilmeteo.it/meteo/cerca?citta=Bari`. So you just have to use `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ilmeteo.it/meteo/cerca?citta=Bari").get()`

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem! But I have another question to ask you if it's not a problem

Comment: please post another question or edit this post and update your question.

Comment: sure, I have updated my initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for your second question:

This is the way I found out to navigate to the "city" page you want to search.

**Step 1:**

Pass the starting letter of the city to the request and get a JSON response.

Ex: If you want to search "Milano", then get the results for letter "m" using this URL `http://www.meteo.it/autosuggest/m.json?`

The sample JSON response is:

```
{
  "url": [
    {
      "ita": "meteo",
      "sea": "meteo-mare",
      "ski": "meteo-montagna",
      "eur": "meteo",
      "wor": "meteo"
    }
  ],
  "results": [
    {
      "code": "15146",
      "value": "Milano (MI)",
      "value_it": "milano",
      "value_en": "milan",
      "url": "ita"
    },
    {
      "code": "20030",
      "value": "Mantova (MN)",
      "value_it": "mantova",
      "value_en": "mantua",
      "url": "ita"
    },
  ]
}
```

From the JSON response get the milano city's code & value_it
Ex: `code=15146 & value_it=milano`

**Step2:**

Construct the URL using retrieved values.
Ex: http://www.meteo.it/meteo/**value_it**-**code**

```
http://www.meteo.it/meteo/milano-15146
```

**Example for Comacchio city:**

Request URL : `http://www.meteo.it/autosuggest/c.json`

JSON Response:

```
   {
      "code": "38006",
      "value": "Comacchio (FE)",
      "value_it": "comacchio",
      "value_en": "comacchio",
      "url": "ita"
    }
```

Construct URL using JSON values:

```
http://www.meteo.it/meteo/comacchio-38006
```

Comment: You have solved my 2 problems! Thank you very much for your availability! You have been very kind! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
String city = "Bari";
String url = "https://www.ilmeteo.it/meteo/cerca?citta="+ city;

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); 
List<Element> rows = doc.select("table[class=datatable] > tbody > tr[id*='']");

for (Element row : rows) {
    System.out.println(row.text());
}
```

Sample Output:

```
13 pioggia e schiarite 25.3° NW 35 / 36 forte51% 0.1 mm modeste0% 3070m1008mb 27°>10km buona 51 7.9
14 pioggia e schiarite 25.5° NW 34 / 35 forte50% 0.1 mm modeste0% 3050m1008mb 27°>10km buona 50 7.6
15 poco nuvoloso 25.5° NW 32 / 33 forte50% - assenti -0% 3070m1008mb 27°>10km buona 50 6.5
16 poco nuvoloso 25.4° NW 31 / 32 forte49% - assenti -0% 3100m1008mb 27°>10km buona 49 5.1
17 sereno 25° NW 30 / 31 moderato50% - assenti -0% 3130m1008mb 26°>10km buona 50 3.3
18 sereno 24.5° NNW 28 / 29 moderato52% - assenti -0% 3180m1008mb 25°>10km buona 52 1.6
19 sereno 23.7° NW 26 / 27 moderato54% - assenti -0% 3220m1009mb 24°>10km buona 54 0.4
20 sereno 22.6° NW 23 / 26 moderato57% - assenti -0% 3190m1009mb 23°>10km buona 57 0
21 sereno 21° NW 21 / 24 moderato68% - assenti -0% 3160m1009mb 21°>10km buona 68 0
22 poco nuvoloso 20° NW 19 / 24 moderato76% - assenti -0% 3130m1009mb 20°>10km buona 76 0
23 nubi sparse 19.4° WNW 18 / 24 moderato80% - assenti -0% 3130m1009mb 20°>10km buona 80 0
24 nubi sparse 19.2° WNW 18 / 23 moderato81% - assenti -0% 3130m1009mb 20°>10km buona 81 0
01 poco nuvoloso 19° WNW 18 / 22 moderato82% - assenti -0% 3140m1009mb 20°>10km buona 82 0
02 poco nuvoloso 18.6° WNW 17 / 21 moderato84% - assenti -0% 3160m1009mb 19°>10km buona 84 0
```

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem! But I have another question to ask you if it's not a problem